# Disable pop-ups in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

How can I disable pop-ups from IntelliJ? I have several projects set up and every time I change, it informs me that it discovered VCS roots (I know, I don't want to set up) and Android project (wrongly). I have to switch between these often, these pop-ups are annoying. Is there a setting to disable them?

Comment: Another way to go to the list of popups: **File > Settings... > Appearance & Behavior > Notifications**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is very easy.

First bring up the Event log window:

[image]

Press the Settings button:

[image]

And from here you can disable the balloon notifications completely or per group:

[image]

Comment: You can also disable baloons completely by disabling the "show balloons" button (blue speech bubble in the event log button bar).