# Remove unwanted popup notifications from android studio

Tags: android-studio

How can I disable unwanted popups on android studio? For example I don't want this popup becouse I can't see logs cause of this:

[image]

I'm using Android Studio 3.5.3 XUbuntu 19 machine. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: I want to know too, they are soooooo annoying!

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. Open event log, click to settings button, disable all popups.

[Disable pop-ups in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32190801/disable-pop-ups-in-intellij)